How do I combine multiple json_group_array for this query correctly?
My aggregate query with group_concat selects from one table, and if there are no results it selects from another:
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    IFNULL(
        SELECT group_concat(SomeColumn) FROM RelationOne,
        SELECT group_concat(SomeColumn) FROM RelationTwo)
FROM MainTable

This produces a comma separated list from either RelationOne or RelationTwo. I want to use json_group_array instead:
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    IFNULL(
        SELECT json_group_array(SomeColumn) FROM RelationOne,
        SELECT json_group_array(SomeColumn) FROM RelationTwo)
FROM MainTable

Which does produce a JSON array with values from RelationOne, but if RelationOne doesn't have data it produces an empty array [] instead of NULL, so if there are any values from RelationTwo they will never be shown because [] != NULL.
How do I accomplish this correctly?

You could try testing for length(array) -- unsure if you need to make it a recursive query.

Try adding HAVING count() > 0, like IFNULL(SELECT json_group_array(SomeColumn) FROM RelationOne HAVING count() > 0, ...).

Don't try to do it all in one query. Move the logic of when to call the second one on RelationTwo into the code that's executing this.

@BarrythePlatipus Testing for length using json_array_length have crossed my mind, but I would have to have the subquery twice... once in the test, and once more to get the result.

@Dogbert I don't have any GROUP BY in my subquery, so I can't use HAVING.

@Shawn I have considered doing the rest in the backend, but seeing as most queries only use RelationOne I would perform an unneccessary subquery most times and degrade performance.

You only execute the second one if you need to...

Add having count() > 0 to your subquery to make it return no rows if there are no values. (Yes, having works without a group by.)
Here's an example:
with numbers(x) as (values (1), (2), (3))
select
  ifnull(
    (select json_group_array(x) from numbers b where b.x < a.x),
    'None'
  )
from numbers a;

Output:
[]
[1]
[1,2]

Now adding having count() > 0:
with numbers(x) as (values (1), (2), (3))
select
  ifnull(
    (select json_group_array(x) from numbers b where b.x < a.x having count() > 0),
    'None'
  )
from numbers a;

New Output:
None
[1]
[1,2]


When I add HAVING count() > 0 to my subquery I get an error saying a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING

Which version of sqlite are you using? It looks like this ability was added in June 2022: https://sqlite.org/src/info/9322a7c21f1c22ba.

Could you try group by null having count() > 0?

Updating SQLite to a newer version made the error disappear, but empty arrays still caused the IFNULL to not have any effect. Adding the GROUP BY NULL together with HAVING seems to have done the trick (both on older and newer versions). Thanks :)
